# You have error in your SQL syntax

Tags: php

can you help me with repair SQL syntax in this query?

```
SELECT percent FROM `freedelivery` 
WHERE freedelivery.id_currency=1 AND freedelivery.price>0 AND freedelivery.price<=2722,5 
AND freedelivery.percent>0 AND freedelivery.percent<=100 AND '2016-10-25' 
BETWEEN freedelivery.`from` AND freedelivery.`till`
```

I'm getting the error "You have error in your sql syntax.".

Thanks

Comment: mysql, like basically ever single programming language, uses `.` as decimal point, not `,` so just write `2722.5` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT percent FROM `freedelivery` WHERE freedelivery.id_currency=1 AND freedelivery.price>0 AND freedelivery.price<=2722.5 AND freedelivery.percent>0 AND freedelivery.percent<=100 AND '2016-10-25' BETWEEN freedelivery.`from` AND freedelivery.`till`
```

Comma on "2722,5" seems out of place. Maybe it's 2722.5

Comment: no. and you shouldn't. and why would you? if you write your queries yourself with hardcoded values, just change the `,` to a `.`. if you build them with variables: you shouldn't do that anyway - use parameterized statements and you won't have to worry.